# Value of variable changing when assigned value through max function

Tags: python, reference

This was a relatively simple problem, to list the elements with maximum value from a nested list.

So I made this function, which

1. finds the element with maximum attribute
2. replaces the maximum attribute by 0
3. Finds the element(s) with max attribute
4. return the elements.

While doing so, I got stuck on step 2 and been there ever since.

Here's the function :

```
def secondMax(data):
    x = max(data, key=lambda x:x[1])

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if(data[i][1] == x[1]):
            data[i][1] = 0
            print(x) #             prints ['yash',0]
    print(x) #                     prints ['yash',0]
    return data
```

and when i run the code, this is the output

***running***

```
# data being fed
data = [['yash', 5.0], ['akash', 5.0], ['harsh', 3.0], ['dj', 4.0], ['ashutosh', 4.0]]
secondMax(data)
```

***OUTPUT***

```
# output 
['yash', 0]
['yash', 0]
[['yash', 0], ['akash', 5.0], ['harsh', 3.0], ['dj', 4.0], ['ashutosh', 4.0]]
```

Now, why is not the second element, (akash, 5.0) being set to (akash, 0)? As far as I can understand, the value of `x` should not change (which is changing) and causing this.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Comparing floats for equality is precarious, it's possible the two different `5.0` aren't *exactly* equal.

Comment: it can be a case when the decimal points go too far, but the value is entered as an integer and then converted using a float() function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```py
x = max(data, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

is returning a reference to the maximum element. So when you set its value to zero during the first iteration doing

```py
        if(data[i][1] == x[1]):
            data[i][1] = 0
```

you are actually changing the value you use for comparison. From now on x[1] will be zero. So basically `'akash'` does not match because you are comparing its value 5.0 with a 0.0, which clearly returns `False`.

Comment: i also think so, buy the documentation doesn't mention anything similar https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: @YashKumarVerma That documentation is for `max` function, which is very clear. This is a general topic related to the reference of objects

Answer (score 0):

The `max_user` in the below code, is referencing the same object i.e., `nested list` in `data`. When we changed the inner value of the nested list, it is getting reflected in our `max_user` as well(as it referenced to the same object, not to inside values).

So, I have taken a `.copy()` of max_user and used it for comparisons.

Made small corrections and you can iterate over list and access it in loop no need of using `range`,

```
>>> def secondMax(data):
    max_user = max(data, key=lambda x:x[1])
    _temp = max_user.copy()

    for user in data:

        if user[1] == _temp[1]:
            user[1] = 0
            print(_temp)
    print(_temp)
    return data
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> secondMax(data)
['yash', 5.0]
['yash', 5.0]
['yash', 5.0]
[['yash', 0], ['akash', 0], ['harsh', 3.0], ['dj', 4.0], ['ashutosh', 4.0]]
```

Comment: You've certainly *simplified* it, but you haven't fundamentally changed anything.

Comment: my question is not how to solve the question, but why is the value of `x` changing ?

Comment: how the edit is any help as your code also has the same confusion. Why is the value of max_user changing?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma You are fast buddy. I have updated code first and written explanation in the second edit. Hope this explanation cleared your doubt. Ask if you need further clarification. :)

Comment: @deceze I have updated the answer with an explanation. It's a nested object reference issue.